# Drag and drop to desktop puts files in Documents folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

Since the last Windows 10 update, when trying to drag-and-drop files to "Desktop", the files are automatically placed in the "Documents" folder, and not on the desktop.

Any ideas on where to change this setting? Or if it's even possible?

P.S. I know this might be a fairly stupid question, but this has started to get on my nerves, and Google hasn't been a good friend this time :(

Comment: What version? Press the Windows key and type `winver` and hit Enter.

Comment: I wonder whether this has something to do with Onedrive which since recently allows your Desktop to sync between devices.

Comment: Are you trying to drag-n-drop files directly to Desktop Screen, or through Windows Explorer folders? you need to check the desktop folder path and verify it's not moved into Documents path

Comment: OneDrive or Business Documents enabled? That redirect saving files.
Also, go to the properties of your C:\Users\<your_username>\Desktop and check Location. may be it's located inside Documents folder?

Comment: Looks like the two shell folders (`Desktop` & `Documents`) may have been merged somehow. See if this applies in your case [Accidentally Merged Music, Pictures, Videos or Downloads Folders](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-folders-merged-music-videos-same-folder/)..